# when i upgrade django-debug-toolbar at 1.6 is does not working

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm create study project using django==1.9.7

when I use django-debug-toolbar==1.4, i works find

and I upgrade 1.4 => django-debug-toolbar==1.6,

and restart runserver, I doesn't woking..

my django-debug-toolbar setting is

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ... #
    'debug_toolbar',
    # ...#
]


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    #...#,
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
DEBUG = True(of course!)
```

when I settings these three parts, 1.4versions works find,

but when I upgrade 1.6(and settings no change) it does not working,

So, I see document [document](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html)

> > Support for automatic setup has been removed as it was frequently problematic. Installation now requires explicit setup. The DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS setting has also been removed as it is now unused. See the installation documentation for details.

It seems ***`automatic setup has been removed`***

I see [Install ducoment(stable version)](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) but I can't find what is different with [Install document(1.4 versions)](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/1.4/installation.html)

I needs some advise. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you might be missing two things.

In your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
]
```

And in your `settings.py`:

```
INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1')
```

assuming you're running on localhost right now. Do these changes and tell me if this helps you.

Comment: @MinHan You're welcome, and if it solved your problem please upvote the answer. Thank you :)